# En JavaScript como creo un boton que en un input de como resultado la A y en otro input de como resultado el 1?

Tags: javascript, html, funciones

Intente darle al button dos clases y llamarla en javascript para ejecutar una funcion y darle un valor diferente a casa clase. El codigo que tengo hasta el momento es el siguiente:

Html:

```
<input id="resultadoA"></input>
<input id="resultado1"></input>
.
.
.
<button type="button" class="A A1">A-1</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('A').addEventListener('click', A)
document.getElementsByClassName('A1').addEventListener('click', A1);

function A(){
    let actual = document.getElementById('resultadoA').innerText;
    let agregar = document.getElementsByClassName('A').value= "A";
    document.getElementById('resultadoA').innerHTML = actual + agregar;
}

function A1(){
    let actual = document.getElementById('resultado1').innerText;
    let agregar = document.getElementsByClassName('A1').value = "1";
    document.getElementById('resultado1').innerHTML = actual + agregar;
}
```

Comment: Esos día resultados los debe dar en momentos distintos o al parejo?

Answer (score 0):

La función [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) devuelve una estructura tipo arreglo, por la que tendrías que iterar para asignar el `eventListener` a cada uno de sus elementos.

Puedes iterar directamente por los elementos con una llamada a `foreach` de `Array.prototype` (dado que el objeto devuelto **no es** un arreglo, sino que solo *parece* uno.

```js
function bodyLoad() {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('A'), function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', A);
  });
  
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('A1'), function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', A1);
  });
}

function A(){
  console.log("ejecutando A");
}

function A1(){
  console.log("ejecutando A1");
}
```

```html
<body onload="bodyLoad()">
  <input id="resultadoA"></input>
  <input id="resultado1"></input>
  <button type="button" class="A A1">A-1</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

A ver si entendí bien, prueba haciendo lo siguiente

```js
const resultadoA = document.querySelector('#resultadoA');
const resultado1 = document.querySelector('#resultado1')

document.querySelector('#btn-resultado').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    resultadoA.value = "A";
    resultado1.value= 1;
})
```

```html
<input id="resultadoA"></input>
<input id="resultado1"></input>
.
.
.
<button type="button" id="btn-resultado">A-1</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName()` retorna un `array` de elementos (aunque haya solo una coincidencia), por lo que no se puede llamar a `addEventListener()` desde ahi, debe ser un elemento individual.

Intenta usando `querySelectorAll()` que retorna una lista de elementos iterable usando `foreach()`.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.A').foreach(element){ element.addEventListener('click', A) });
document.querySelector('.A1').foreach(element){ element.addEventListener('click', A1); });
```

No me queda claro cual es la logica, pero al parecer estas usando `.innerHTML` para obtener valores de inputs, siendo que debes obtener el valor usando `.value`. Y en elementos button, el contenido se obtendria con `.innerHTML`.

```
document.getElementById('resultadoA').value; // valor del input id=resultadoA
```